# C# Facebook sdk 6.1.4 logout

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Sorry if I ask this question again but I really can't get rid of this problem. Im my application I got 2 accounts, I log in with one and everything is perfect I load albums and pages in some combobox, the I try to login with another account trying to get same information but the albums and pages I get are mixed with the ones of the other account. I tried everything to log out but is not working. I would.t ask but I read and tried so much code!! Thanks

Here is where I "try" to logout:

```
    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        comboBox3.Items.Clear();

        //var fb = new FacebookClient();
        //var logoutUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new { access_token = this.AccessToken, next = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" });
        //webBrowser_01.Navigate(logoutUrl);

        logout = "ok";

        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        var logoutUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new { access_token = this.AccessToken, next = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" });

        webBrowser_01.Navigate(logoutUrl);
    }
```

here is where I load data:

```
     private void WebBrowserNavigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(logout.Trim().Length==0)
        {

        // get token
        var url = e.Url.Fragment;
        if (url.Contains("access_token") && url.Contains("#"))
        {
            //this.Hide();
            url = (new Regex("#")).Replace(url, "?", 1);

            this.AccessToken = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url).Get("access_token");

            //MessageBox.Show(this.AccessToken);

            fb = new FacebookClient(this.AccessToken);
            fb.PostCompleted += new EventHandler<FacebookApiEventArgs>(fb_PostCompleted);



            //ALBUM BEST

            //Get the album data

            dynamic albums = fb.Get("me/albums");
            foreach (dynamic albumInfo in albums.data)
            {
                //Get the Pictures inside the album this gives JASON objects list that has photo attributes 
                // described here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/
                //dynamic albumsPhotos = fb.Get(albumInfo.id + "/photos");
                string jdata = albumInfo.ToString();
                JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jdata);
                string aid = (string)obj["id"];
                string coverphoto = (string)obj["cover_photo"];
                string name = (string)obj["name"];
                //MessageBox.Show(aid + " - " + name);

                Albums_Name[name] = aid;
            }


            //ROUTINE PER INDIVIDUARE LE PAGES

            dynamic All_Accounts = fb.Get("me/accounts");
            foreach (dynamic accountInfo in All_Accounts.data)
            {
                //Get the Pictures inside the album this gives JASON objects list that has photo attributes 
                // described here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/
                //dynamic albumsPhotos = fb.Get(albumInfo.id + "/photos");
                string jdata = accountInfo.ToString();
                JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jdata);
                string aid = (string)obj["id"];
                string name = (string)obj["name"];
                Access_Token_Pages = (string)obj["access_token"];
                //MessageBox.Show(aid + " - " + name + " - " + Access_Token_Pages);
                Accounts_Name[name] = aid;

            }



            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            //comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            comboBox3.Items.Clear();



            foreach (DictionaryEntry element in Albums_Name)
            {
                if (element.Key.ToString().IndexOf(@"Timeline Photos") == -1 && element.Key.ToString().IndexOf(@"Mobile Uploads") == -1 && element.Key.ToString().IndexOf(@"Profile Pictures") == -1)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add((string)element.Key);
                }
            }

            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(Default_Album);


            //ROUTINE PER INDIVIDUARE GLI ALBUM DELLE PAGES
            fb2 = new FacebookClient(Access_Token_Pages);
            fb2.PostCompleted += new EventHandler<FacebookApiEventArgs>(fb_PostCompleted);

            foreach (DictionaryEntry element in Accounts_Name)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show((string)element.Value);
                dynamic Pages_Albums = fb2.Get((string)element.Value + "/albums");
                foreach (dynamic albumInfo in Pages_Albums.data)
                {
                    //Get the Pictures inside the album this gives JASON objects list that has photo attributes 
                    // described here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/
                    //dynamic albumsPhotos = fb.Get(albumInfo.id + "/photos");
                    string jdata = albumInfo.ToString();
                    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jdata);
                    string aid = (string)obj["id"];
                    //string coverphoto = (string)obj["cover_photo"];
                    string name = (string)obj["name"];
                    //MessageBox.Show(aid + " - " + name);

                    All_Pages_Album[name] = aid;
                }

            }

            foreach (DictionaryEntry element in All_Pages_Album)
            {

                comboBox3.Items.Add((string)element.Key);
            }

            comboBox3.SelectedIndex = comboBox3.FindStringExact(Default_Pages_Album);

        }

    }

    } 

    Thanks
```

Comment: Show is your code  otherwise we can't help you..

Answer (score 0):

This is problem caused by 2 reasons. .net browser/ie and facebooks never working logout function.

You have to write a second software that kills and opens your original one when the user logs out from facebook or finishes his work. Without killing its executable webbrowser control never dies :) And the previos users session keeps alive no matter what.

Also for facebook logout disable cookies except for the site being visited in ie... You have to look up that setting

Comment: Test it very well! Sometimes it won't work and users' Facebook accounts will mix up and cause problems. I tried your solution... used your solution... and failed bad

Comment: Well I tryied a lot of solution but the one I posted works, when you register your app (in fb developer) you gotta choose also an "app domains" it will be provided by facebook itself like mine "https://glacial-beyond-3099.herokuapp.com/", I tried tried a lot and it works.